# In PowerShell, how to copy a directory recursively and change its name at the same time

Tags: powershell, recursion, directory, copy

I have the following directories structure:

```
Foo
+--Bar
   +--Baz
      +--Garply
         +--...
```

With PowerShell, I would like to copy Baz to Foo recursively and change its name to Qux, to get the following structure:

```
Foo
+--Bar
|  +--Baz
|     +--Garply    
|        +--...    
+--Qux
   +--Garply
      +--...
```

If I call

```
Copy-Item .\Foo\Bar\Baz .\Foo\Qux -Recurse
```

I get:

```
Foo
+--Bar
|  +--Baz
|     +--Garply    
|        +--...    
+--Qux
   +--Baz
      +--Garply
         +--...
```

which is not what I expect.

I can mess around with targeting to .\Foo and renaming the folder Baz to Qux later, but this is an additional complication and has an additional risk of names clashes.

Is there a way to do that with just single `Copy-Item` invocation? Are there any other simple options?

Answer (score 1):

`Copy-Item .\Foo\Bar\Baz .\Foo\Qux -Recurse` only puts `Baz` below `Qux` if the directory `Qux` already exists.

Try something like this:

```
$src = '.\Foo\Bar\Baz'
$dst = '.\Foo\Qux'

if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $dst -Type Container) {
  $src += '\*'
}

Copy-Item $src $dst -Recurse
```

or use separate copy statements depending on whether the destination folder does or doesn't exist:

```
if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $dst -Type Container) {
  Copy-Item '.\Foo\Bar\Baz\*' '.\Foo\Qux' -Recurse
} else {
  Copy-Item '.\Foo\Bar\Baz' '.\Foo\Qux' -Recurse
}
```